# Is there any way to convert OWL/RDF to OWL/XML FILE?

Tags: python-3.x, owlready

I want to use owlready.But is there any way to convert my ontology OWL/RDF file to OWL/XML? or Is there any python library which can we used to OWL/RDF file?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [Protege](https://protege.stanford.edu/) to import your ontology in OWL/XML format. Basically Protege provides several formats to store your ontology. Another option could be using [OWL API](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki).